# How to print the oracle db table like shown below?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table like shown below:

```
name field value
---- ----- -----
a    p     1
a    q     2
b    p     5
c    q     7
d    p     4
e    p     3
e    q     2
.    .     .
.    .     .
.    .     .
```

Expected Output :

```
name p   q    .   .   .   .   .
---- --- ---  --- --- --- --- ---
a    1   2
b    5
c        7
d    4    
e    3   2
.    .   .
.    .   .
.    .   .
```

How to the field elements in column like shown above...

Comment: simply use `unpivot`

Comment: Are the values in the `field` column in a fixed list of possible values, known in advance? If YES, then you can do this with `pivot` (or pivot manually, as shA.t has shown already). If NOT then you will need dynamic SQL (not recommended); in that case it is better to do the pivoting in the reporting layer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
select name,
    sum(case when field = "p" then value else 0 end) p,
    sum(case when field = "q" then value else 0 end) q,
    ...
from yourTable
group by name;
```